# Showing different data sets with FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flatlist

I have 3 data sets (Movies, Shows, and Games) that I want to show with a `FlatList` depending on the selected tab. I am also using React Navigation.

I came up with 3 possible solutions to show the relevant info:

- One `FlatList` that changes it's `data` property on tab change
- One visible `FlatList` and two hidden `FlatList`s based on the tab
- Using React Navigation to change the screen to one with a relevant `FlatList` based on the tab

What would be the optimal approach?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @jnpdx What would be the optimal approach?

Comment: Based on what criteria?